# Python restframework return ImportError: No module named but no syntax error

Tags: python, api, django-rest-framework

Im creating a api following a tutorial and I am facing an error when run ning the code
I am trying to call a model from an app called myapi
There is no syntax error but i get the error: ImportError: No module named 'researchformeapi.myapi'

This is my strucutre

```
researchformeapi
  -- apis
    -views
    -...
  -- myapi
    -models
    -...
```

I'm trying to call the models in myapi in apis.views

```
from rest_framework import generics
from researchformeapi.myapi import models
from .serializers import ApiSerializer

class ListTodo(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = models.Myapi.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer

class DetailTodo(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    queryset = models.Myapi.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ApiSerializer

from researchformeapi.myapi import models
ImportError: No module named 'researchformeapi.myapi'
```

Comment: `from myapi import models` try that.

Comment: I tried that but i got an error

Comment: It is like i can't call myapi without call researchformeapi.myapi

Comment: did you register your app in settings?

Answer (score 0):

After you installed an app, always put it into the settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'myapi',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what I did, but it is working fine. Thank you for your tipps guys. I appreciate it.